# Is there a java container to execute java source files directly?

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I find it boring to `compile` and `run`,

is there a container that can automatically do the compile work so that I just need to save the java source code and `run`?

Interpret?

```
0:  sipush        4711
3:  istore_0
4:  getstatic     java.lang.System.out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
7:  ldc           "Please enter a number> "
9:  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.print (Ljava/lang/String;)V
12: getstatic     Factorial.in Ljava/io/BufferedReader;
15: invokevirtual java.io.BufferedReader.readLine ()Ljava/lang/String;
18: invokestatic  java.lang.Integer.parseInt (Ljava/lang/String;)I
21: istore_0
22: goto          #44
25: astore_1
26: getstatic     java.lang.System.err Ljava/io/PrintStream;
29: aload_1
30: invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
33: goto          #44
36: astore_1
37: getstatic     java.lang.System.err Ljava/io/PrintStream;
40: aload_1
41: invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/Object;)V 
44: iload_0
45: ireturn
```

Comment: What is your platfom? How do you compile?

Comment: I'm on linux ,compiling with javac.

Comment: Java is a compiled language. Before you run it, you have to compile it.

Comment: Are you looking for a program that checks every few minutes and compiles all the java sources in a folder?

Comment: Set up a shell script that hides the compilation. Use an IDE. Set up a file watcher that compiles it on save. Use an actual build tool and a CI machine. What's the point, though?

Comment: Use an IDE and click the "Run" button. C'mon, mate.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use "Eclipse" IDE for java? It's so powerful and saves a lot of work. It comes with incremental compiler, you don't need to compile separately, just run your program easily.

Comment: No, I ask this question in order to avoid IDEs..I really don't like that way..

Comment: Then you're doing Java wrong.

Comment: @new_perl Strong IDEs are the only thing that make Java bearable, and they solve your problem. A problem I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. If you want to merge 2 commands into one.. You could easily do the following in linux command line..

```
javac ...&& java ..
```

Comment: I don't want to add new commands each time I create a new source file.Java is essentially interpreted language, this feature is not available for historic reason, not that it's impossible.

Comment: Add an argument you mean? It all comes down to writing a script that does the lookup for you before you call this script

Comment: Yes, this feature is built into many languages, but not java though.Which make cli developers very happy.

Comment: Java is not "essentially an interpreted language" in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: @Brian Roach,I updated the reason I say it's essentially interpreted.

Comment: And that ... would still be incorrect. Unless of course in your world every compiled language is "essentially interpreted" because they produce instructions for a given machine, and you could always just ... write in assembly.

Answer (score 0):

This approach -- writing everything in a single java file -- is not usable except for "toy" applications. For anything complex, you want to distribute your logic to multiple classes, and that's when an IDE like Eclipse becomes useful.

For toy applications, you can trivially create a `~/bin/javac-java` that compiles and executes if compilation succeeded.

```
javac $1 && java `basename $1 .java`
```

Comment: Do you know such a  `javac-java`?

Comment: it doesn't exist, I assume you know how to write simple shell scrips